# Spring 4.0 WebSocket with Spring Security 3.2.3 in Grails

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, spring-websocket

I need to add realtime updates to a system. I'm using Grails 2.5.0 with Grails Spring Security Core 2.0 RC4, which is based on Spring Security 3.2.3. There's a Grails plugin to add Spring 4.0 WebSocket support (https://github.com/zyro23/grails-spring-websocket/tree/1.3.x), but I'm unsure of how to handle authentication. How can I integrate the authentication?

Alternatively, I can start a separate web app to handle the realtime updates using Spring Security 4.0 with the latest WebSocket plugin, but I would prefer to use my current, production ready authentication system instead of attempting to clone the current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spring security support for websocket starts with spring security 4.
what you could do is securing message subscriptions and sending (client --> server) with a `ChannelInterceptor`. maybe this example helps: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2546